# Arabic file names changed to unicode

Tags: locale, encoding, filename, unzip

Copied zip file of site backup from old host which had Arabic file names, when unzipped on new installation of Ubuntu file names are somehow changed to unicode.

Original file name :
`إدارة-المكتب-الفني-للمدير-العام-1024x198.jpg`

Name changed to `#U0627#U0633#U062a#U0634#U0627#U0631#U0627#U062a-1024x198.jpg` Not sure if I picked up the right file as I can't identify the correct files.

Tried using `wget` but there are about 6786 files which seems like a chore doing one by one and plus I will not know what files to remove as there will be duplicate files with different name and will occupy unnecessary space. Tried using `convmv -r -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 .` but of no use.

```
ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2016/03$ convmv -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 #U0627#U0633#U062a#U0634#U0627#U0631#U0627#U062a-1024x198.jpg
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Your Perl version has fleas #22111 #37757 #49830 
convmv 1.15 - converts filenames from one encoding to another
Copyright (C) 2003-2011 Bjoern JACKE <bjoern@j3e.de>

This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; it may be copied or modified
under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 or 3 as published
by the Free Software Foundation.

 USAGE: convmv [options] FILE(S)
-f enc     encoding *from* which should be converted
-t enc     encoding *to* which should be converted
-r         recursively go through directories
-i         interactive mode (ask for each action)
--nfc      target files will be normalization form C for UTF-8 (Linux etc.)
--nfd      target files will be normalization form D for UTF-8 (OS X etc.)
--qfrom    be quiet about the "from" of a rename (if it screws up your terminal e.g.)
--qto      be quiet about the "to" of a rename (if it screws up your terminal e.g.)
--exec c   execute command instead of rename (use #1 and #2 and see man page)
--list     list all available encodings
--lowmem   keep memory footprint low (see man page)
--nosmart  ignore if files already seem to be UTF-8 and convert if posible
--notest   actually do rename the files
--replace  will replace files if they are equal
--unescape convert%20ugly%20escape%20sequences
--upper    turn to upper case
--lower    turn to lower case
--parsable write a parsable todo list (see man page)
--help     print this help
ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2016/03$
```

Is there any way I can find what encoding it is using and change it back to original file name?

[Old hosting showing the files in correct encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csS74.png)
[New hosting showing the files in unicode with hash encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGl2H.png)

Comment: One thing I see is that your locale is broken, which doesn't make it easier. Try to run `sudo update-locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`. Then check if you can run the `locale` command without warning messages.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~$ sudo update-locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

Comment: Ok. Then log out, log in again, run the `locale` command in a terminal window, and show us the output.

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Good, then your locale has been fixed. Now you may want to give it another shot with the files with Arabic names. Btw, you may need install Arabic fonts, e.g. the fonts-arabeyes and fonts-kacst packages.